# Create a dynamic list using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html

I'm new to web development. I'm trying to create a website with some basic tools. I'm facing a syntax problem while trying to write HTML and PHP at them same file. I want to create a dynamic select list based on my database. 
Here is my code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['Eingabe1'])){
    // Get the value of the textfield
    $Aufgabe=$_POST['Eingabe1'];
    $ins_query="INSERT INTO Aufgaben(inhalt)
                VALUES('$Aufgabe')";
    //get value for the dynamic list    
    $sel_query="SELECT inhalt from aufgaben";
    $result=$conn->query($ins_query);
    // check whether the query has succeeded
    if (!$result) {
            echo "Aufgabe konnte nicht hinzugefügt werden"; }
        else{
            echo '<html>
<title>
Start Seite
</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form name="f" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" >
<br><br>
<table width=70% style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<tr>
<td><p class="serif">Aufgabe auswählen</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>'.

$res2=$conn->query($sel_query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res2)){

'<select id="Aufg">
<option value="Aufgabe Auswählen" selected="selected"> Aufgaben Auswählen</option>
<option>' echo $row["inhalt"]; } '</option>                          
</select>
</td>   
<td><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="c"><font color="white">Erledigt</font></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Mitarbeiter" id="Mitarbeiter" placeholder="Mitarbeiter .."></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log out"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>' ;  } }

$conn->close();
?>
```

My problem is that I wrote HTML in a PHP `else` statement and then I wanted to write another PHP code to generate the dynamic list inside the `<select>` tag. Now I'm facing syntax error saying **unexpected echo** which I wrote on the `<select>` tag. I just need to know the right syntax for this and maybe an idea whether the dynamic select is properly written. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks for disliking the post instead of helping someone who is new to this.

Comment: As a hint: if you just started programming, don't go the old way: we've all struggled with mixing up markup and logic for years, but nowadays, you should split that up into PHP code and seperated templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what you should do

```
<?php
  // Check if required post variable is empty, then print empty response
  if(empty($_POST['Eingabe1'])) die("");
  // Create mysql connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect(...);
  // Execute the SELECT statement
  $result = ...
  // Throw message if there's no result
  if (!$result) die("Aufgabe konnte nicht hinzugefügt werden");
?>
<!-- Normal html -->
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- Header stuff here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Your body -->
    <select name="Aufg">
       <?php
          // Your loop here and echo out the select's options
       ?>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
  // Close the connection 
  $conn->close();
?>
```

Note: `die` basically means echo out the message and terminate immediately. So, the rest won't be printed out

Comment: I agree with what you wrote thats why i said my code is unreadable, but the html i wrote is realted to the php else statement. thats why i didnt seperate them.

Comment: Based on the code you've written I think this will produce output as you expected

Comment: it has worked as expected thanks a lot!. but im still facing a small problem the input checkbox and textfield after the select are not excuted. the select works dynamically fine. but the other two inputs doesnt appear. do you have an idea how to fix this ?.

Comment: @IhebAbouda May I take a look at your current code? Maybe through [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com)

Comment: yep i shared it, can you check that please?

Comment: Give me the link @Abouda